# check_box_tag default checked for remember me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating a login system and would have a remember me checkbox. I would like to make this checkbox default to checked so that the user can uncheck if they do NOT want to be remembered.

Currently I have

```
<%= label_tag :remember_me %>
<%= check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me] %>
```

How do I add the option to default this to checked?

This seems like it should be simple, but I've tried looking at the api and monkeying with my code to make it work, but no luck! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `params[:remember_me] = true` in your controller action before rendering this view.

Answer (score 11):

This should work.

```
 <%= check_box_tag :remember_me, :checked => true %>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work unfortunately, but the accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: Have edited the answer, it should have been `true` or `'checked'` instead of checked.

Comment: The problem is, that the checkbox is then always checked. Also if you uncheck it and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
# view:
<%= check_box_tag(:flag, 'yes', @flag) %>

# controller:
def foo
  @flag = params[:flag] || !params[:utf8]
end
```